# How to create predefined groups of widgets in QT Designer to add them to a QScrollArea from the final code

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyqt6

Lets say I create a tapi phone application in QT Designer that contains a simple phonebook.
There is no code so far, but a basic layout. (see screenshot)

As you can see, the phonebook does contain some sample records, you could call it a template of what a record should look like.

Is there a way to create predefined groups of widgets in QT Designer, which I can later use in my code to add new phonebook records to the QScrollArea?

[image]

Comment: You could create a "template" as a separate "Form widget" in designer. Then, create QWidget subclasses with those UI files and add them to that scroll area within the code logic of your program.

Comment: Simple but effective... Will try it out. Thank you

Comment: There is also another alternative: use a QListWidget and a custom item delegate for it. It may become tricky if you need advanced in-place editing (eg. to change the values of the fields), but if you are not interested in that (for example, if you provide a separate dialog to edit the fields of each entry), that could be worth it: a phone book may have hundreds if not thousands of entries, and that means having thousands (even tens of thousands) of widgets, which could really affect performance. Or you could even find a common ground for both: use an item delegate that displays each entry, ->

Comment: -> but also return an editor (a custom QWidget) that *resembles* the same appearance, while providing editing capabilities, whenever the user clicks somewhere within the phone book entry. I suggest you to look up for some documentation and examples about item delegates, as that may come handy in any case.